# Finding shaded cells in Word

Tags: ms-word, cells, shading

I am looking for some help with coming up with a macro that will help me find all shaded cells in Word regardless of shading color, then change the color of the shading to just ONE shade of color, for consistency sake. From all my research so far, it seems that is not possible without actually putting in the color information in the macro. Any help will be much appreciated! Thank you!

```
Sub ChangeShadingColor()
Dim myTable As Table
Dim cll As Cell

For Each myTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
myTable.Select
For Each cll In myTable.Range.Cells
        If cll.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorBrightGreen Then
           cll.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorBlue
        End If
Next
Next myTable
End Sub
```

Comment: Reverse the logic and look for cells that are not transparent fills

Comment: I am actually a novice in creating Word macros. This is what I have so far. How do I modify this so that I can find cells that are not transparent fills? Thank you.

Comment: Modify what? Please take a moment to read in the site's [help] about how to ask effiective questions. StackOverflow is not a free code-writing service or a tutorial site: a certain amount of effort is expected on the questioner's part.

Comment: Thanks Cindy for your comment. I apologize for my lack of knowledge. Hoping to learn more and become more well-versed on this site.

Comment: Instead of searching for color = Green or any other color - search for color <> wdColorWhite  (see answer below)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned - change your search to look for cells NOT with no color, ie. <> white

Change

```
If cll.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorBrightGreen Then
   cll.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorBlue
End If
```

To

```
If cll.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor <> wdColorWhite Then
   debug.print "Found Cell with Color: " & cll.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor
End If
```

Comment: Thanks dbmitch for you answer but it doesn't seem to work for me. Not your fault, I probably was not clear in my question. I am working with documents where different shades of blue have been used to shade cells in tables. My goal is to change those different shades of blue to the same shade of blue,.Hope this makes sense. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad you figured it out

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Thanks, dbmitch for helping kick-start my brains in that direction.

```
Sub ChangeCellShadingColor()
Dim myTable As Table
Dim cll As Cell

For Each myTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
myTable.Select
For Each cll In myTable.Range.Cells
    If cll.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor <> wdColorAutomatic Then
        cll.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = -603930625
    End If
Next
Next myTable
End Sub
```